# Prime factors bounded by $k$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $S$ be the set of integers with largest prime factor bounded by a given positive integer $k$. Is there a formula for the asymptotic density of such a set $S$?

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: These are called "smooth" or "friable" numbers, and there is a vast literature about them.

Comment: @JoshuaStucky : I would think you're talking about _sets_ of numbers being "smooth" or "friable" or whatever the adjective is, rather than about the numbers themselves being "smooth", etc., since _every_ number belongs to such a set.

Comment: @MichaelHardy No, I am talking about numbers themselves being smooth, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $k$ is fixed, then the simple bound $|S\cap[1,x]|\leq(\log_2 x)^{\pi(k)}$ shows that the aymptotic density of $S$ is zero. For stronger bounds, see Chapter III.5 in Tenenbaum: Introduction to analytic and probabilistic number theory.

Answer (score 3):

You're saying no prime factors bigger than the $n$th prime number appear. So we're looking at the set
$$
\{ p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_n^{e_n} : (e_1,\ldots,e_n) \in \{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}^n \}.
$$
There is a one-to-one correspondence between such numbers and the $n$-tuples $(e_1,\ldots,e_n),$ by uniqueness of prime factorizations.

If the sum of the reciprocals of these numbers is finite, then the asymptotic density must be zero. The sum of the reciprocals is
$$
\left( 1 + \frac1{p_1} + \frac1{p_1^2} + \cdots \right) \cdots \left( 1 + \frac1{p_n} + \frac1{p_n^2} + \vphantom{ \frac1{p_1^2} + {} } \cdots \right),
$$
and that is finite.